# Unable to Post Messages using Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

For some reason this code doesn't post when i press enter i am unable to figure out why i have layed out my Index and jquery file Please Help

index.php

```
<div id="display_box">
 <b> MESSAGE</b>
 <hr />

 </div>
  <div id="message_box">
 <textarea id="message">
 </textarea>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function{
        $('#message').keyup(function(e){
            if(e.keyCode == 13){
                var value =$(this).val();
                $('#display_box').append(value + "<hr/>");

                $('this').val('');

            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: $('this').val(''); would be $(this).val('');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have error here, You missed `()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                          ^^
```

Check console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

Also `$('this').val()` should be `$(this).val()`

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/0ayo919c/)

Comment: Thanks alot i do not know how i missed that :)

Comment: @jake123 Please check in **Developer Tool console** of browser before posting question in SO.

Comment: i am getting a error that says Reference Error $ is not defined

Comment: Its okay i sloved it it was because i didnt have a jquery mini file

Comment: You have not include Juqery library

Answer (score 1):

replace 
$(document).ready(function{
with

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```